# For $A \in L(V,V)$ where $(V, (\cdot,\cdot))$ is an inner prod space, $\exists !$ $z(x)$ such that $(x,Ay) = (z(x), y)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, linear-transformations, inner-products

> Let $A$ be a linear transformation from $V \to V$ where $(V, (\cdot,\cdot))$ is a finite-dimensional inner product space.  Consider the inner product $(x, Ay)$ for fixed $x$ and varying $y$.  Then there exists a unique vector $z(x)$ depending on $x$ such that $(x, Ay) = (z(x), y)$ for all $y \in V$.

What is the simplest proof of this?  My book says it's a consequence of Gram-Shmidt orthonormalization, but I'm not seeing that.

---

However, I guess we can say we have an orthonormal basis $b_i$, so that putting $x = \sum x_i b_i$ and $y = \sum y_i b_i$ we get $(x, Ay) = \sum x_i A(y_i)$ by linearity of $(\cdot, \cdot)$ and definition of orthonormal.

So let $A(y_i) = \sum a_{ij} b_j$.  Then further rewriting gives $(x, Ay) = \sum_{i,j} a_{ij} x_i$.  We want a vector $z = \sum_i z_i b_i$ such that $(x, \sum_i z_i b_i) = (x, Ay)$ or $\sum_{i} x_i z_i = \sum_{i,j} a_{i,j} x_i$.

I see now, it must be $z_i = \sum_j a_{i,j}$.

To prove uniqueness it's what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me (as in your sugestion) the most natural proof is to express $z(x)$ in terms of a certain basis $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ of $V$ (assume this basis is orthonormal). Then we need to find coefficients $\lambda_i$, such that 
$$z(x)  =\lambda_1 v_1+\ldots+\lambda_n v_n.$$
Then 
$$(y,z(x)) = \sum_i y_i \lambda_i$$
and
$$ (x,Ay) = \sum_j x_j (Ay)_j = \sum_{i,j} x_j a_{ji}y_i. $$
Comparing indices, we need that (take $y = v_i$ and enumerate all $i$'s)
$$ \lambda_i = \sum_j x_j a_{ji}.$$
This means that $$z(x) = (v_1,\cdots,v_n)A^T \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: How do you show uniqueness, is it by construction?

Comment: It follows since $\lambda_i$ has to be equal to the expression give by the sum in the second last equation.

Comment: If you want to read more about this, the vector $z(x)$ depends linearly on $x$. Therefore the map $V \rightarrow V: x \mapsto z(x)$ is a linear map. The matrix in a certain basis of this map is called the hermitian conjugate matrix of $A$ in that basis.